# Why does 'spherically symmetrical' function $\phi$ consist of $r^2$, $p^2$, $\vec{r}\cdot \vec{p}$?

Tags: symmetry, geometry, invariants

Why does the spherically symmetric function $\phi$ can only depend on $r^2$, $p^2$, and $\vec{r}\cdot \vec{p}$, but not on $r$?
I thought $\phi$ could also depend on $r$ because $r$ is always bigger than zero, so $r = 3$ indicates every point on the ball whose radius is 3.

[image]

Specifically, I'm wondering about the part in the blue highlighting.

Comment: Note that $\mathbf{r}$ is a vector, but not the magnitude of $\mathbf{r}$

Comment: Could it mean that the function $\phi (\vec{r}, \vec{p})$ is a second order homogeneous funciton of $r$ and $p$? otherwise, you might have many other terms.

Comment: Magnitude of a vector is invariant under rotation.

Comment: The question isn't worded great, the author just wants to point out that a spherically symmetric function must be writeable only in terms of the dot products of the position/momentum vectors. $\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r} = r^2$, but of course $\sqrt{r^2} = r$ is also allowed, just not the full vector $\vec{r}$ or $\vec{p}$ as those depend on direction and so a function which must be written in terms of the vectors can not be spherically symmetric (i.e. not depend on direction)

Answer (score 0):

$\phi$ *can* depend on $r$. For instance, $\phi=r$ is spherically symmetrical, and you could write it as $\phi=\sqrt{r^2}$, so it fulfills the condition mentioned in the solution. It just can't depend on the individual components $x$, $y$, $z$, $p_x$, $p_y$, or $p_z$ in other combinations.

The point it's getting at is that it can't depend on the direction of $\vec{p}$ or $\vec{r}$, but only on the magnitude of the two vectors and their dot product.